# Google Apps script: OnEdit function doesn't read the range

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a larger function run when cell D4 in Sheet 2 is edited, but the macro doesn't read the range function. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZE5h.png)

I'm wondering if it's because it's specified elsewhere in the code I've written or if I haven't been specific enough with where the data is coming from?

I'm still very new to this (my first project!) so please talk in easy terms!

Comment: Please [edit] to put text as text and not as image - as it is easy to copy/paste and search.

Comment: It's because you're running it from the script editor, which doesn't have a edit event. Trigger functions run automatically on edit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when you start a script from the editor that should be started by a trigger.
Therefore, the edited cell range cannot be retrieved and an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you function requires permission and Simple Triggers cannot run functions that require permission. - [onEdit.restrictions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)